# iOS 11 UIWebView JavaScript Pop-up Issues

Tags: gwt, uiwebview, dropdown, ios11

I have an issue with updating an app for use with iOS 11. I have the native app, which uses a UIWebView to show a GWT JS application.

However, pop-ups are not working in this app for iOS 11. They can open, a value can be selected, and then they will save the value and close, but then they will reopen exactly as they were prior to closing, and this will continue. If I have 2 drop downs, then the first will have the issue described above, but if I then open a second I will see the values from the first drop-down until I have clicked somewhere else on the screen to close it.

The second time the drop-down comes up it does not automatically close on selection, but does seem to change the value. Additionally, if I close the drop-down without having anything selected then it will pop-up with the same number of items in the list, but all blank, as though the initial pop-up is somehow feeding values into the second pop-up.

I have eliminated the possibility that it is solely a code issue, as the same exact native and web code has the pop-ups working as intended on iOS 11.

I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this, either because you have experienced this issue yourselves or even just in general issue debugging hints for iOS 11, as this is relatively new to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was replacing UIWebView with WKWebView from WebKit framework. For the moment I didn't found any better solution to this issue.

Be sure you add WebKit.framework to your target.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a few minor problems with my application after converting, such as the way I handled internal navigation and caching. But that was just a learning curve and this has solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Having the same problem, but cannot use WKWebView as this is a Cordova/Phonegap app.

Comment: Yeah, that's a complicated issue with cordova, you can create a custom popover either in javascript or in native part and use that

Answer (score 0):

This is an ios issue with UIWebView, as mentioned in the previous answer. Replacing this with WKWebView will help to fix this. For anyone who is not able to replace to WKWebView, this issue is fixed in xcode 9.2 beta-2 version. So you can build your app with xcode 9.2 beta-2 (hopefully the stable version will have this fix as well), and try testing in ios 11.2.